# xcode crashes when I click on the console to check the output

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Facing an issue with xcode. 
I'm trying to develop an app that gives me the weather info. The build succeeds, but everytime I click on the console to check the output (to search, copy etc) xcode crashes.

The following text comes from the reporting tool to Apple,

Application Specific Information:
   ProductBuildVersion: 7C1002
   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): -[__NSCFString    characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
   UserInfo: (null)
   Hints: None

Here's the code I'm running,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Hyderabad/forecasts/latest")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let webContent = data {

            let decodedContent = NSString(data: webContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            //print(decodedContent)
            let weatherSiteSourceArray = decodedContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">")
            print(weatherSiteSourceArray)

//                if weatherSiteSourceArray?.count > 0 { 
//                
//                    let weatherInfo = weatherSiteSourceArray![1]
//                    print(weatherInfo)
//                }
            }
    }
    task.resume()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

though the report tool informs me  UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): -[__NSCFString    characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds.

I am unable to figure out where this is happening. 
From what i have learned you can print an array in Swift using the                 print(items: Any...)  method.

help on this would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking is there any element in your array and then you are trying to read second element. There are chances that your array is having only one item in it and hence when you are choosing weatherSiteSourceArray![1], it fails as accessing element 2 is out of bound of array.

if weatherSiteSourceArray?.count > 0 {

```
            let weatherInfo = weatherSiteSourceArray![1]
```

Either check for

```
     if weatherSiteSourceArray?.count > 1
```

or use first element i.e.

```
          let weatherInfo = weatherSiteSourceArray![0]
```

I have no idea of swift and assume it uses zero based index for array.

Comment: Thanks ash, worked ! Have to be more careful while working with arrays. :)
Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to figure out exactly which line is causing the crash. Try commenting out these three lines:

```
let decodedContent = NSString(data: webContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//print(decodedContent)
let weatherSiteSourceArray = decodedContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">")
print(weatherSiteSourceArray)
```

And if you code doesn't crash after that, then try commenting in you code one line at the time until you have the line crashing.

Another thing:

Looking at your code I'm guessing that maybe this line:

```
let weatherSiteSourceArray = decodedContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">")
```

might be the one causing your problems. Its a bit risky and brittle to try separating your content based on an HTML string like that. The second that string changes (and it will :-)), you've lost.

A better way would be to receive the data in pure `JSON` or `XML` if they have an API providing that.

Just a thought :-)

Comment: thanks for the tips. will keep this in mind while debugging. 
Also yes splitting based on the HTML of a website isn't the smartest as it WILL change at some point. this was just from a pure tutorial point of view. Will be careful and i will keep your advice in mind. Thank you once again :)